# get the value from a custom data attribute with plain Javascript and without using getElementById

Tags: javascript

I need to get the custom data attributes from these fields.

```
<input type="text" name="FirstName" data-type="string" placeholder="First name" autocomplete="off" >

<input type="text" name="phone" data-type="number" placeholder="Last name" autocomplete="off" >
```

This is the code to select the fields without using getElementById:

```
 var elements = this.elements;

            this.elements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
            var elements = this.elements;
            var group = elements.length;


            for (var i = 0; i < group; i++) {

                this.controller.validate({
                    field: elements[i],
                    value: elements[i].value,
                    dataType: e.target.getAttribute('data-type'), //   <---- ERROR: This is undefined
                    optional: e.target.getAttribute('data-optional')//   <---- ERROR: This is undefined
                });

            }
```

using the `element.getAttribute('data-type')` works fine in *Chrome* and *Firefox* but it **Fails** on *internet explorer*

**The challenge:**

> I need to get the value of these custom attributes from any browser:

- I can't use any third party libraries.
- I can't use **getElementById** because these fields are dynamic.

any ideas?

Comment: How exactly does that fail in Internet Explorer? IE has supported `setAttribute()` and `getAttribute()` since forever.

Comment: I'm getting this error `SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'getAttribute'` It is supported on edge, but if you fallback to version 11, 10, 9 or 8 it's not supported

Comment: That means that what you think is a reference to a DOM element is actually something else. You'll have to post more code in order for anybody to help.

Comment: @LeoJavier: Show us how you select the dynamic fields if not by `getElementById`, that's the problem not `getAttribute`

Comment: Where is `e` defined? I presume its from an event handler but how is that handler registered?

Comment: IE doesn't use the property name "target" in its event objects. Instead, it's called "srcElement".

Comment: `e` has been pass as an argument

Comment: @Pointy is correct, [See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target#Compatibility_notes) So judging from that i guess youve missread your exception. `getAttribute` is undefined but not causing the error. `target` will be undefined and the root cause.

Comment: You can write `(e.target || e.srcElement).getAttribute(...)`

Comment: taking a look to this too @Pointy thanks!

Comment: Pointy! Your were right!!! Thank you so much! since target wasn't available on IE I was getting an undefined value.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you've updated your question we can see that your error is in calling `getAttribute` on `e.target` which may not exist depending on how you listened to the event, and which browser you are in.

Surely, it would be better to just attach an all-round validation handler to the inputs, ignore `e` and simply check all the inputs at once for validation.

The contents of that handler may look something like this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {

  var type = elements[i].getAttribute('data-type');
  var optional = elements[i].getAttribute('data-optional');

  console.log('type/optional:', type, optional);

  this.controller.validate({
    field: elements[i],
    value: elements[i].value,
    dataType: type,
    optional: optional
  });
}
```

If you insist on using the event, then perhaps you should only check the particular input that has dispatched the event, mitigating the need for `getElementsByTagName`:

```
var target = e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement;

var type = target.getAttribute('data-type');
var optional = target.getAttribute('data-optional');

console.log('type/optional:', type, optional);

this.controller.validate({
  field: target,
  value: target.value,
  dataType: type,
  optional: optional
});
```

Please note that `data-optional` does not exist as attributes in your markup, so their value is `null`.

Comment: mmmm.... this may be the issue... thanks Shennan I'm taking a look right now..

Comment: @LeoJavier it's very likely that your code is failing in IE9 due to the use of `e.target`. Also, you should consider both my suggestions above.

Comment: Thank you Shennan you were right too, the `e.target` is not available within IE environment.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use;

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-type]');
```

Comment: querySelectorAll is partially supported by IE8